# Visual noise on the main page

Tags: discussion, design

- Does anyone actually make any use of the list of recent tags?
- Does anyone actually make any use of the list of recently awarded badges?

Comment: Related: [ *What is the purpose of the Recent Tags cloud?* ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31585/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-recent-tags-cloud) on MSO.

Answer (score 4):

Recent tags are total noise. The list of recently awarded badges
is not of significant use, but I'm sure that some users get an
ego-boost from knowing that details of their recently acquired badges
are broadcast to all and sundry.

Answer (score 1):

The recent tags is constructed from the last (n) questions with at least 1 upvote, aggregated by tag -- so it's a walk down "what topics is this *website* generally about" without having to read and parse each question.

The recent badges is an invitation to discover why badges exist, and what they are for.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/badges-positive-only/

These elements exist to familiarize new users who may be encountering the homepage for the first time -- and also as shortcuts (particularly recent tags) for experienced users.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed as much. But my question is: do people *really* use them?